# Tag addition request

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

What does the community feel about adding a [parted-magic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parted-magic) tag to the site? Seems a fair few people are unfamiliar with it enough, to completely miss that it is the name of the distro in questions I have asked lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a problem with it. I've created the tag on [this Q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96883/way-of-compiling-installing-software-in-a-package-manager-less-distro). Feel free to go back through your prior questions and retag them.